# Confusion regarding taylor expansion

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Given $u(v,p)$ and $g(v,p)$ is relate by below equation

$$\frac{dp}{dv}=\frac{g-u_v}{u_p}=f(v,p)$$

This is how I got it but I do not know why a direct differentiation using$\frac{u}{v}$ method does not work. Unless I having the wrong concept regarding differential equation and taylor series expansion.

Consider equation below and $p(v_0)=p_0$

$u(p_1,v_0+h)-u(p_0,v_0)=g(p_0,v_0)h$

I use the same method as previous post [Is the assumption consider cheating in mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429464/is-the-assumption-consider-cheating-in-mathematics) to find what is $p_1$ that satisfy the above equation with little changes, that is taking the coefficient of $h$ as $g(p_0,v_0)$ and coefficient for $h^n,n=2,3,4,...$ as $0$ and derive up to 3rd order expansion.

and letting

$f=\frac{g-u_v}{u_p}$

will get

$p_1=p_0+hf_0-\frac{h^2}{2}(\frac{u_{pp}f^2+2u_{pv}f+u_{vv}}{u_p})_0+O(h^3)$

since 
$u_pf+u_v=g$

$g_p=u_{pp}f+u_pf_p+u_{pv}$

$g_v=u_{pv}f+u_pf_v+u_{vv}$

$p_1=p_0+hf_0+\frac{h^2}{2}[f_pf+f_v-(\frac{g_pf+g_v}{u_p})]_0+O(h^3)$

I derive up to the 3rd oder and get

$p_1=p_0+hf_0+\frac{h^2}{2}[f_pf+f_v-(\frac{g_pf+g_v}{u_p})]_0+\frac{h^3}{6}[(f_pf+f_v)_pf+(f_pf+f_v)_v-(\frac{(g_pf+g_v)_pf+(g_pf+g_v)_v}{u_p})+\frac{3g_p(g_pf+g_v)}{u_p^2}-\frac{3f_p(g_pf+g_v)}{u_p}]_0+O(h^4)$

This method is very ineffective in deriving the term as for higher order term, it have more and more derivative to deal with, So I tried a direct differentiation on function of f as below.

First derivative

$f=\frac{g-u_p}{u_v}$

Second derivative

$f_pf+f_v$

$=(\frac{g-u_v}{u_p})_pf+(\frac{g-u_v}{u_p})_v$

$=\frac{u_pg_pf-u_pu_{pv}f-gu_{pp}f+u_vu_{pp}f+u_pg_v-u_pu_{vv}-gu_{pv}+u_vu_{pv}}{u_p^2}$

But it is different from the derivative from method above.

$f_pf+f_v-(\frac{g_pf+g_v}{u_p})$

Correction: I think i found my own mistake

Assuming $p_2=p_0+hf+\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+...$

Inputting below equation and taking $g=u_pf+u_v$

$u(p_2,v_0+h)-u(p_0,v_0)$

$=gh+\frac{h^2}{2}(g_pf+g_v)+...$

Which mean a full taylor expansion of f will show full taylor expansion of g?

$u_p(\frac{h^2}{2}(f_pf+f_v)+\frac{1}{2}(u_{pp}(hf)^2+2u_{pv}(hf)(h)+u_vv(h^2))=\frac{h^2}{2}(g_pf+g_v)$

$f_pf+f_v=\frac{u_pg_pf-u_pu_{pv}f-gu_{pp}f+u_vu_{pp}f+u_pg_v-u_pu_{vv}-gu_{pv}+u_vu_{pv}}{u_p^2}$

Comment: Where is this from? Can you provide some context (e.g. what class this is from, what theorems you know and think are useful)?

Comment: $f'$ is a derivative with respect to what variable?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier because there's a dp/dv and not del p/del v I think it's safe to assume that p is a function of v, and hence f is a function of v

Comment: @D.R. Then what about the $f_p$ and $f_v$ later on?

Comment: If you want this answered correctly, I suggest you reveal where it is from, I don't see any way it could be correct as stated

Comment: Can help to verify? I think I found my own mistake that is I wrongly taking $p_1$ as the solution of the DE $\frac{dp}{dv}=\frac{g-u_v}{u_p}=f(p,v)$ after getting full expansion of g on the right hand side, I am able to get $f_pf+f_v$ same as the direct differentiation.